# A timer in a Python game

Tags: python, pygame

Could someone help me out with making a timer in python?, what I need help with is that the 'Handle_caught' method should contain a timer that makes the players speed increase for five seconds, the players speed is increased when a global variable is changed to True.

The speed token class:

```
class Addspeed(games.Sprite):
image = games.load_image('addspeed.png')
speed = 2

def __init__(self,x,y = 10):

    super(Addspeed, self).__init__(image = Addspeed.image,
                                   x = x, y = y,
                                   dy = Addspeed.speed)

def update(self):
    if self.bottom>games.screen.height:
        self.destroy()

def handle_caught(self):
    self.destroy()


def increasespeed(self):
    global speedbuff
    speedbuff = True

def decreasespeed(self):
    global speedbuff
    speedbuff = False
```

How the players speed is increased:

```
speedbuff = False
    def update(self):
    global inventory
    global speed
    """ uses A and D keys to move the ship """

    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_a):
        if speedbuff == False:
            self.x -= 3
        elif speedbuff == True:
            self.x -= 6


    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_d):
        if speedbuff == False:
            self.x+= 3
        elif speedbuff == True:
            self.x+=6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `speedbuff` to an integer value (number of frames for the power-up to last), instead of boolean, and in the player's update method decrement it until 0. Like this:

```
if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_a):
    if speedbuff > 0:
        self.x -= 6
    else:
        self.x -= 3

...

if speedbuff > 0: speedbuff -= 1
```

Since 0 is interpreted as `False`, your if statements could simply be `if speedbuff:`, if you were so inclined.